# which is the best option for the sentence

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference if we use the below three words in a sentence. Is there any grammatical error?

The boy "told"/"asked"/"said to"  his teacher to explain the passage.

Answer (score 1):

> The boy told his teacher to explain the passage.

The boy commands his teacher to explain the passage, as if he were her superior or parent. This would be considered rude in most classroom settings.

> The boy asked his teacher to explain the passage.

A polite request; much less rude than the above.

> The boy said to his teacher to explain the passage.

Not very natural sounding. It probably would imply a command as in the first example. A more natural way to say this, and with a little less implied rudeness on the part of the boy, is

> The boy said to his teacher, "Explain the passage."

Answer (score 0):

The "**told**", if used in that sentence, sounds like the boy *issued a command*.  Boys shouldn't command their teachers, but it would still be grammatically correct.

The "**asked**" is most appropriate as far as interaction between boys and their teachers goes.

The "**said to**" is similar to "**told**".

All three are grammatically acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The boy told (demanded) his teacher to explain the passage.

The boy asked (polite) his teacher to explain the passage.

The boy said to (almost as rude as told) his teacher to explain the passage.